# MapKit annotations does not show after first launch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Whenever I load my app and I access locationViewController to show restaurants nearby my current location the annotations does not show up for the first launch. Therefore, I have to go back to previous VC and then open location VC again before it finally shows in the correct place.

Here is the code for viewDidLoad() in LocationVC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Search for restaurants around user location.
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurant"

    request.region = map.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { (response, error) in

        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }

        for item in response.mapItems {

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            annotation.title = item.name

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it happnes when you launch app first time?. is it working fine after first launch or kill app as well.

Comment: After opening locationVC for the first time it only works until I kill the app.

Comment: try to move your code in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Still does not make any difference. While trying to figure out what is wrong I have realized that after first launch the annotations are loading completely in the different place, whereas when I dismiss VC and open it again then they populate nearby my current location.

Comment: Please show your code for opening locationVC.